# jQuery resizable strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, css

working demo with strange behavior: http://crawfordcomputing.com/AkadineWebOS/#/

If you grab the right div-window border and resize horizontally, It goes wonky vertically. Same for all the windows you can open with the icons. Everything is draggable too, and Jetris works. (check link for info)

This is an Angular single page app. My div-window is defined:

```
<div ng-repeat="pane in panes">
    <div id="{{pane.windID}}" style="position: absolute; top: {{pane.x}}; left: {{pane.y}}; border: 2px solid black; min-height: 70; overflow: hidden">
        <div style="padding:2px; overflow: auto; background-color: grey; border: 1px solid black">
            <span style="float: left; text-align: left" ng-bind="pane.title"></span><span style="float: right; text-align: right" ng-click="closeWindow(pane.objID)">X</span>
        </div>
        <div compile="pane.content" style="background-color: white; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid black; overflow: auto;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the window div id="{{pane.windID}}" has two children, a title bar and a content pane. So when resizing the window I tried asloResize the content pane. That was weird since it did not account for the titlebar. So I did this: (all variables are defined previously if not defined in the function)

```
objParent.resizable({
                handles: "n, e, s, w",
                minWidth: 250,
                minHeight: fullHeight, 
                //fullHeight is parents height, don't wanna colapse one liners
                //titlebar (child0) resizes just fine due to floating
                //child0 size bugs alsoResize child1, let's also it manually
                resize: function (event, ui){ 
                    //subtact title height from parents height
                    contentHeight = objParent.innerHeight() - objChild[0].innerHeight();
                    //width is fine
                    contentWidth = objParent.innerWidth();
                    objChild[1].css({'width':contentWidth, 'height':contentHeight});
                }
            });
```

Now see, when resizing, I aslo want to asloResize just the content pane, not the title bar. So I am trying to set the content pane's size manually, width is fine, but content pane height equals parents height minus the title bars height.

The problem is that if you resize horizontally first, the vertical goes wonky. Once you grab the bottom and resize vertically the bug goes away, you can then resize however you want perfectly without problems. It only happens if you resize horizontally first.

Why does this happen? I doubt the bug is actually in the draggable resize function because you can stop the bug by resizing vertically first, and then it works perfect. This happens on all browsers.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div with id `window100-obj951` does not have a css height set initially. The contained div with `compile="pane.content"` does not either.

Resizing vertically changes the css height property of both these divs.

Resizing horizontally changes the width of both, but the height only of the contained div.

The containing div has `overflow:hidden`, so if its height is set, the height of the contained div is not significant. Hence, having the height of the containing div set masks the fact that the height of the contained div is actually being changed to be wonky.

[All this can be seen using Firebug and inspecting the element while resizing]

Comment: Ok so it's fixed. a combination of giving both it a dummy height of 10px in the inline style, and then copying the height calculation from my resize function and adding it the the pane open function and presetting the heights there. Thank you Chris for putting me on the right track. Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes! It seems that although innerHeight and outerHeight properties exist page load out of the box, height does not and needs to be dealt with programmatically.